# How to get RowID from SQLiteDB in ListView?

Tags: android

I have a ListView that is fed by an SQLiteDB. On each row returned, I have a clickable TextView that onClick should delete the item on that row. So I need to find the sql rowid, so I can call deleteItem(rowid).

I've tried putting in an invisible TextView that I fill with the sql rowid as the ListView is populated, it works. But I set content view to R.layout.list_view and the invisible TextView is in R.layout.list_item (custom layout for each item line), so I can't seem to access it.

How do I go about making this work or is there a better way?

Here is the code that populates the listview:

```
    private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { CommonDbAdapter.KEY_NOTES };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Here is my current click listener, I'm not sure how to differentiate between a click on the item, which returns the item to another activity and a click on the textview that would delete the item.

```
    itemList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    itemList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("TEXT", ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

I was originally trying to get the rowid and use a simple onClick set in the layout. But had problems getting the rowid.

```
public void clickDelete(View view) {
    mDbHelper.deleteNote(rowid);
}
```

Comment: you seem to be overthinking how to do this i think.. show us the code for populating the listview and your listview adapter. it will be easier to tell you what you should change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick way to get a click listener for just your textview:

replace your lines:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

with this:

```
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    final TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hello " + t.hashCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
});
```

now, your `text1` view will have an onclick listener, and you can do whatever you want.  you need to store the `rowId` somewhere accessible from inside the `onClick` method though.

this doesn't exactly answer the question i guess, but it gives you a click listener for an individual view in the listview.

you really should implement a custom `CursorAdapter` class to do something like this, although you could hack around and retrieve the `rowId` from somewhere

or you could instead use an invisible textview and add an onclick listener to it(like i've shown above), grab it's value(which is a rowId), and perform an operation.

Comment: Ok, so I used your ClickListener to handle the "delete" textview. I store the rowid in an invisible textview. onClick, I call deleteNote... that works. Then I also have the listview ItemClickListener in onCreate that I posted above, that handles selecting items... that works. So I have a listview ItemClickListener and a ClickListener for a view that is inside a listview that already has an ItemClickListener... it works but is this OK?

Comment: if it works, sure it's OK.  you will want to create a custom adapter at some point if you need to add more features

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `CursorAdapter`?  If so you can query the `Cursor` directly for the rowid.

You may want to use [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) instead of an OnClickListener. This will set you up with the ListView, the position and the id.  I believe if you are using a CursorAdapter that the id given to you is the actual rowid of the row in the database.

**Edit:** if using `OnItemClickListener` is not possible, you'll have to change to `CursorAdapter` from `SimpleCursorAdapter` to do this. In your bindView method you'll have access to the rowid of the View you are creating, and you can reference this in the `OnClickListener` you create.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: If I use an OnItemClickListener, how can I tell difference between whether I'm clicking on the textview of the item or the textview that deletes items?

I already have an OnItemClickListener that returns the clicked item to a field in another activity.

Comment: i suggest using a custom adapter rather than a `SimpleCursorAdapter`... that way you can more easily define a view's `onClick` method and `tag`